# Issue on association in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, model-associations

Here is my issue. I have two models (Construction and Customer)

```
class Construction < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :works
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :constructions
end
```

I would like to associate a Customer to a Construction during the creation of a new construction.
To do so I have de following controller's method (which is obviously false)

```
def create
  # @construction = Construction.new(constructions_params) (commented)
  @construction = Construction.new(customer: @customer)
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
  @construction.save!
end
```

from the params I am able to understand that the construction is not saved because it is not attached to a customer and so cannot be created.

I am new to rails and I have been struggling for hours now..

Hope someone will be able to help me.

thanks a lot

Comment: Your customer_id under `params[:construction][:customer_id]` maybe ? `puts params.inspect` and check it

Comment: Show your form. Do `puts params.inspect` and show the output too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to revert the order:

```
@customer = Customer.find(params[:construction][:customer_id])
@construction = Construction.new(customer: @customer)
@construction.save!
```

you need to assign `@customer` instance variable before you use it. Otherwise it's `nil` and nothing is assigned to the new `Construction` record.

Comment: might be better to use `@construction = @customer.constructions.build`

Comment: use `params[:construction][:customer_id]` (updated the code)

Comment: i spoke too fast...
It is "working" creating a construction associated to the correct customer, but I am not able to retrieve all the information from my simple form for.. 
Name, address, volume, duration are now set to nil..

Comment: @BrianRid please post a complete question then. including the params that are being submitted and the intended result

Comment: Ok i will try to be more specific : 
Here are the params after the following : 
 @construction = @customer.constructions.build(customer: @customer)

Params : "construction"=>{"name"=>"Test", "address"=>"Paris", "duration"=>"12", "volume"=>"12", "customer_id"=>"25"},
 "commit"=>"Créer"}

Then the save! is a success. 

but i am redirected on my index where i am not able to find my newly build construction.

I checked with rails c --> except the filed customer_id all the other one are set to nil

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `customer_id` available at the point of form creation I reckon that you can do something like this.

Also given the belongs_to relations with the `customer` on the construction, you should be able to update the `customer_id` on the construction.

```
def create
  @construction = Construction.new(construction_params)
  if @construction.save
    # whatever you want to do on success
  else
    # Whatever you want to do on failure
  end
end

# Given you have construction params

private

def construction_params
  params.require(:construction).permit(:all, :the, :construction, :attributes, :customer_id)
end
```